# 2 Part: 1: Not able to crete AVD 2: Could not find AVD or SDK manager

Tags: android-studio

2 Part question:

- Not able to crete AVD because "No system images installed for this target" for Android L

(I am using Android Studio 0.8)

- Could not find AVD manager or SDK manager for imported project on Android Studio 0.8

What I am trying to do: Just trying to import project from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-JobScheduler and run it on emulator.

**Checked: I have executed android from path_to_sdk/tools/android and made sure that Android SDK L and all system images are downloaded.**

Update: now when I am trying to run emulator-XXX from path_to_sdk/tool/ I am getting following error:

> "emulator: ERROR: Missing system image:
>   /Users/pawannimje/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools/../platforms/.DS_Store/images/system.img"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you still have to run 'path_to_sdk/tools/android' and install the Android L SDK and Android L System Image for ARM/x86/...

Comment: Done that already. I have checked everything under Android L in SDK manger which includes SDK, ARM/x86 system images. Still having the issue.

Comment: now when I am trying to run emulator-XXX from path_to_sdk/tool/ I am getting following error:

"emulator: ERROR: Missing system image: /Users/pawannimje/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools/../platforms/.DS_Store/images/system.img"

Comment: You are telling me that you launched 'path_to_sdk/tools/android' and installed the Android L images? "sdk/tools/../platform‌​s/.DS_Store" doesn't look right; in linux it would be something more like "sdk/tools/../platform‌​s/21/...". It looks like you are trying to boot a AVD which you somehow created **before** installing the images. You have to use that same 'path_to_sdk/tools/android' to create a new AVD.

Comment: that **before** part does sounds something which could be the reason... let me look into it